# Illegal constructor Java script

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to Javascript and so I am just trying to implement a basic queue, but I get the error:  Uncaught TypeError: Illegal Constructor.  I really don't know what is wrong.  Here is my code.

```
class node{
  constructor(id,value){
    this.id = id;
    this.value = value;
    this.next = null;
  }
  getId(){
    return this.id;
  }
  getValue(){
    return this.value;
  }
  setValue(value){
    this.value = value;
  }
  getNext(){
    return this.next;
  }
  setNext(next){
    this.next = next;
  }
}


class queue{
  constructor(){
    this.head = null;
    this.size = 0;
    this.tail = null;
  }
  enqueue(value){
    let newNode = new Node(this.size,value); //This is line 39
    if (this.size === 0){
      this.head = newNode;
      this.tail = newNode;
      this.size++;
      return;
    }
    this.tail.next=newNode;
    this.tail = newNode;
    this.size +=1;
  }
  dequeue(){
    if (this.size > 0){
      let temp = this.head.getValue();
      this.head = this.head.getNext();
      this.size --;
      return temp;
    }
    return null;
  }

}


var q= new queue();
q.enqueue(1)
console.log(q.dequeue);
```

It throws it on the line in enqueue where I make a new node.  Is there some limitation to making objects in objects that I don't know? I have attached the error message.  Line 39 in the where I make a new node object.[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w53rr.png)

Comment: Typo here `new Node(this.size, value);`. The class name is `node` not `Node`

Comment: What does question have to do with React?

Answer (score 0):

No there aren't any limitations here. Change Node to node. The casing should match. I suggest formatting the code correctly and looking up some of the JS conventions (classes should be PascalCase, or at least follow the same convention).
Also don't use var, it's an outdated feature with scoping issues especially for newbies.

Comment: So your advice should be "Change node to Node".

Comment: Yes that is rather what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the typo of class name for node in `function enqueue(value).`

Here is the working code after updating the same-

```
enqueue(value){
    let newNode = new node(this.size,value); //This is line 39
    if (this.size === 0){
      this.head = newNode;
      this.tail = newNode;
      this.size++;
      return;
    }
    this.tail.next=newNode;
    this.tail = newNode;
    this.size +=1;
  }
```